# Don't change background color in editable selectbox when the drop down is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom

I need your help,

How can the JavaScript coding below be modified such that the background color in the input box won't unshade when the [↓] is clicked to display the avaliable options. The only time that both elements (input/select) should unshade, is if the user removes focus from both elements entirely by clicking on some other element in the page.

Scratching my head with this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shade = "yellow"
    var unshade = "white"

    window.onload = function() {
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')

                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {                

                    if (x[i].readOnly == false) {

                        if (x[i].id == "refdocs_input") {

                            x[i].onfocus = function() { 
                                    this.style.backgroundColor = shade
                                    document.getElementById('refdocs_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = shade
                                    document.getElementById('refdocs_select').style.backgroundColor = shade
                            }//end function

                            x[i].onblur = function() {
                                    this.style.backgroundColor = unshade
                                    document.getElementById('refdocs_wrapper').style.backgroundColor = unshade
                                    document.getElementById('refdocs_select').style.backgroundColor = unshade
                            }//end function
                        }//end if

                    }//end if

                }//end for
    }
</script>
```

here in the HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#refdocs_select { 
    left: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetLeft); 
    width: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetWidth);  
    clip: expression("rect(2px auto 20px " + (this.previousSibling.offsetWidth - 20) + "px)"); 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#refdocs_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
}
#refdocs_input {
    border: 0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="refdocs_wrapper">
<input id="refdocs_input" type="text"><select id="refdocs_select"> 
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
    <option value="DEF">DEF</option>
    <option value="GHI">GHI</option>
    <option value="JKL">JKL</option>
    <option value="MNO">MNO</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Created JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qScbR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only changing the background colour when the input is in focus. However, selecting the dropdown arrow means that the input is then OUT of focus (only one element can have focus at once).
You'd need to listen to the focus events on the input and select to get the effect I think you desire.